# how to find a closest polynomial of degree at most $n$ to $f \in C[a,b]$ with max norm

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

I have been studying part about finite-dimensional normed spaces. and then I have a some problem on studying. here is problem

> Show that for each integer and each function $f$ in $C[a,b]$, there is a polynomial of degree at most $n$ that is closest to $f$ in the max norm on $C[a,b]$

Please teach me how to attempt to solve this problem! Thanks!

Comment: Hint: the subspace of polynomials of degree at most $n$ is finite dimensional (hence closed and locally compact).

Comment: @Shaun I tired to show P is compact. but I think it is not correct blow my solution

Comment: Please share this attempt before your question is closed as off topic.

Answer (score 2):

What follows is a long hint:

Let $F$ be the space of all polynomials of degree $\leq n$, then $F$ is a finite dimensional subspace. Let $f\in C[a,b]$, and consider
$$
S = \{g \in F : \|g-f\| \leq \|f\|\}
$$
and consider
$$
h:S\to \mathbb{R} \text{ by } g \mapsto \|g-f\|
$$
Check that $S$ is compact, and that $h$ is continuous. Now can you try to complete the proof?

Comment: I'll try through your help !

Answer (score 0):

Let $F$ be the space of all polynomials of degree $\leq n$, then $F$ is a finite dimensional subspace. Let $f\in C[a,b]$, and consider
$$
S = \{g \in F : \|g-f\| \leq \|f\|\}
$$
and consider
$$
h:S\to \mathbb{R} \text{ by } g \mapsto \|g-f\|
$$
Let's Check that $S$ is compact, and that $h$ is continuous.

(1)since $f$ is continuous. such that by extrme value thm there is maximum value 
$$
\Vert f \Vert =M
$$ 
thus
$$
S = \{g \in F : \|g\| \le \|g-f\|+\|f\|=2M\}$$
then
$$
inf\{\|f-g\|:g\in S\}=inf\{\|f-g\| : g \in  F\} 
$$
and clearly $S$ is bounded by $2M$ and closed thus $S$ is compact

(2)show h is continuous.
for $g_1,g_2 \in S$
$$
|h(g_1)-h(g_2)|=|\|g_1-f\|-\|g_2-f\|| \le \|g_1-g_2\|$$
thus h is Lipschitz function. that is h is continuous. by the Extreme value Theorem, f has minimum at some point g* in S. this is a closest point.

Answer (score 0):

You don't precise which norm your using for compactness. I might be wrong but here it seems you're thinking of compactness for points in R while here the problem deals with functions. So you want to minimize | p - f |(x) in P.

Comment: Compactness here is only used in the finite dimensional space of polynomials having degree at most $n$. In an finite dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-vector space, all the norms are equivalent, hence define the same topology and the same compact sets.